# HTML output value of specific array element number in JSON

Tags: html, arrays, json

Attempting to output a specific element in my nested arrays. A simple example of my array is: Data = {John, Jack, Jason, Nick} that is nested in the array, IndividualNames. In my HTML I would like to print only Jack.

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    "key": "NameData",
    "modulName": "Name Data",
    "children": {
      "key": "IndividualNames",
      "modulName": "Individual Name",
      "children": {
        "key": "Data",
        "modulName": "Data"
      }
    }
  }
],
```

My HTML so far for what I would like the webpage to display:

```
Name: &nbsp&nbsp #IndivualNames[1].Data
```

This HTML output is exactly what I am saying in the HTML (Name: &nbsp&nbsp #IndivualNames[1].Data) and not the array value (Jack).

If I have the HTML as

```
Name: &nbsp&nbsp #IndivualNames.Data
```

The HTML output is JohnJackJasonNick. So essentially outputting the entire array.

What is wrong with the syntax of [1] to break the HTML code?

Comment: If I got you correctly, your `#IndividualNames.Data` is the object that holds all 4 names. So if you only want to print the name `John`, you should try `Name: &nbsp&nbsp #IndivualNames.Data[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to display *name* in your HTML file. But it seems that you are passing it wrongly. There's is lacking of your codes but I assume your looking for something like this.

```js
let IndivualNames = [{NameData: 0, Data:['John0', 'Jack0', 'Jason0', 'Nick0']},{NameData: 1, Data:['John', 'Jack', 'Jason', 'Nick']}];
console.log(IndivualNames[1].Data,'Sample data from json') //Output: ['John', 'Jack', 'Jason', 'Nick']

let text = 'Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;'+IndivualNames[1].Data[0];
console.log(text,' => Here do not include the variable in string') //Output: Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;John

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Maybe this could help you in someway.